# Promise in JavaScript still executes code synchronously

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, es6-promise

```js
function loadTables() {
  refReview.on("value", function(snap) {
    var data = snap.val();
    var file11 = "";


    for (var key in data) {
      console.log("keys retrieved", data[key].revieweeID);

      var idOfReviewee = data[key].revieweeID;


      var promise = getData(idOfReviewee);
      promise.then(function(returnedFnLn) {
        console.log(returnedFnLn);
      });
      console.log("yeah");
    } //end of for loop

  });
}
```

why does it executes the console.log("yeah") when promise.then is not yet done?

```
function getData(idRev) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    getDataToUsers = firebase.database().ref("users").child(idRev);
    getDataToUsers.once("value", function(snap) {
      var fnLn = snap.val();
      var first = fnLn.firstname;
      var second = fnLn.lastname;
      forPromiseFnLn = first.concat(second);

      resolve(forPromiseFnLn);
    });
  });
}
```

Output of console should be

```
keys retrieved: ,
(firstname and lastname retrieved),
yeah
```

But instead gives

```
keys retrieved ,
yeah,
(firstname and lastname retrieved)
```

Comment: sorry about the caps . didint mean to . didint notice it was caps hehe sorry again

Comment: yeah, but why is it that it executes the code console.log("yeah") when its not yet done retrieving data from firebase?

Comment: You need to read up on how promises work. They are asynchronous.

Comment: sorry about that charlietfl. just read about promises :( thank you very much. but is my code well structured for you?

Comment: Your function fires after it gets data. I don't see any need for a promise in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what async stands for.

Whyle your data get's fetched, javascript continues to execute the rest of your script. And since your `console.log("yeah")` ist not part of your promise, it's being executed before the data has been fetched.

Either you have to do it sync (what's not good if you try to fetch data) or you can move your `console.log()` inside your `promise.then()` function.

Comment: okay.  now i understand in great detail about promises  but can i ask one last thing? is my code well structured?

Comment: I think so, can't see anything to complain about.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `for...in loop` is synchronous and a Promise is asynchronous.

If you want to stop the loop until each Promise resolve you have to

> Switch to ES2017 `async/await` syntax

Change your code like this

```
function loadTables() {
    refReview.on("value", async function(snap) {
        var data = snap.val();
        var file11 = "";

        for (var key in data) {
            console.log("keys retrieved", data[key].revieweeID);
            var idOfReviewee = data[key].revieweeID;

            var returnedFnLn = await getData(idOfReviewee);
            console.log(returnedFnLn);
            console.log("yeah");
        }
    })
}
```